Automatic reload of Okular config file
I've got a script that switches my system between night and day modes.
In Okular, during night mode I use the accessibility option "Change Colors" which inverts the colors of documents.
In practice, if I do this in the UI this updates ~/.config/okularpartrc, adding the lines:
[Document]
ChangeColors=true

Naturally, in my switching script I update this config file.  However, this doesn't trigger Okular to re-read the config file.
Is there a nice way of doing this? I would prefer not to restart Okular, as I could have many documents open.  "Reloading" with F5 just reloads the document rather than the config.
